# How to remove deconvolution noise in style-transfer neural network

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, style-transfer

Im studying style-transfer networks and right now working with this [work](https://github.com/lengstrom/fast-style-transfer) and here is [network description](https://github.com/lengstrom/fast-style-transfer/blob/master/src/transform.py). The problem that even with adding TV loss there is still visible noise which is breaking quality of result.
Can someone recommend some articles of ways of removing such noise during network training?

Thanks

[image: Example of noise]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deconvolution` noise is because of the uneven overlaps between the input and the kernel which creates a checkerboard-like pattern of varying magnitudes. One fix is to use `resize-conv` method as mentioned in this [article](https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/).

`Resize-conv` replaces `transpose convolution` with `image scaling`  followed by a `2D convolution`. In tensor flow, the 2 steps are: `tf.image.resize_images(...)` and `tf.nn.conv2d(...)`. Another tip from the authors is to call `tf.pad(...)` prior to the convolution method and only use `Nearest Neighbour` resize method.

Comment: yeah, i tried to do upsampling using tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor
but that gave not such good result in style transfer overall and increase training time.
Is there any other methods of doing this? what if i use kernel size 4x4 with stride 2 instead of 3x3, or 3x3 with stride 3? It will give even number of overlaps.

Comment: yes having kernel size multiple of stride might also help. The above method worked for me in GANs to produce smoother image.